# Disabling model's after_find only when called from certain controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, callback

I have an after_find callback in a model, but I need to disable it in a particular controller action e.g.

```
def index
  @people = People.find(:all) # do something here to disable after_find()?
end

def show
  @people = People.find(:all) # after_find() should still be called here!
end
```

What is the best way to do it?

1. Can I pass something in to .find to disable all/particular callbacks?
2. Can I somehow get the controller name in the model and not execute the callback based on the controller name (I don't like this)..?

Help!

Answer (score 2):

> @@callback_after_find

don't forget restore it. maybe its more better.

```
class People
  def self.skip_after_find
    @@callback_after_find = false
    yield
  ensure
    @@callback_after_find = true
  end 
  def after_find
    return unless @@callback_after_find
    ...
  end
  private
  @@callback_after_find = true
end

People.skip_after_find do
  @people = People.find(:all) # do something here to disable after_find()?
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a flag on your model to define if you want execute or not after_find.

```
class People
  @@callback_after_find = true
  def after_find
    return unless @@callback_after_find
    ...
  end
end
```

In your controller you can now activate or not this callback

```
def index
  People.callback_after_find = false
  @people = People.find(:all) # do something here to disable after_find()?
end

def show
  @people = People.find(:all) # after_find() should still be called here!
end
```